# How to convert RBG data into a Image

Tags: rgb, converters

I'm doing a easy cybersecurity challenge where I'm given a data file with only RBG codes like the following ones:

> [(0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 2), (1, 1, 3), (1, 1, 3), (1, 1, 3), (0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 2), (1, 1, 3), (0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 2), (1, 1, 3), (1, 1, 3), (1, 1, 3), (1, 1, 3), (0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 2), (1, 1, 3)]

As you may wonder, the file is much wider and longer and I don't know how I should convert all this RBG data into an image. I tried using a python script in a Lubuntu1204 but it still gave me some errors and I didnt get the image I was looking for.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: you can use canvas in html web browser, where you draw pixel by pixel, there are options to save it as png base 64 ...